# Mirror text from input field to html span using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've got a form that outputs a product price to an input field, depending on user dropdown selections. It's a form that submits the final calculated price, so the price has to remain as a form input.

However, I want to hide the input and display a span with static text instead, which updates to reflect what's currently calculated in the input.

The code that changes the input itself is hosted elsewhere, and cannot be altered. I need a solution that piggybacks on this somehow.

I can't figure out how this would work, but this is all I could come up with:

```
$("#priceField").change(function() {
    $('#price').html($(this).val());
});
```

`#priceField` is the hidden input. `#price` is the html span.

I'm guessing I need to somehow call this whenever any input is changed? I'm not sure, but I'm sure scratching my head over it...

Comment: please post your HTML  form code

Comment: What is `$(input "#priceField")` supposed to mean? That's not valid Javascript syntax. Did you mean `$("input#priceField")`?

Comment: Is `#priceField` the hidden input? A `.change()` handler doesn't make sense, since the user can't edit it. It doesn't run when the value is changed by some other Javascript.

Comment: You should just find the code that updates the hidden input, and have it update the span as well.

Comment: Why don't you just make the input `readonly` instead of hidden?

Comment: readonly works, but its still selectable in iOS, which isn't smart enough to not allow me to edit it. An edit window pops up, and nothing happens when you try to change the text, but it's still stupid.

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you would to **call** or **trigger** the `$('#priceField').change()` after setting it up:

```js
$('#priceField').change(function () {
  // text is more appropriate
  $('#price').text($(this).val());
});

$('#applyBtn').click(function() {
  calcPrice();
  
  //Call the change manually
  $('#priceField').change();
});

$('#triggerBtn').click(function() {
  calcPrice();
  
  //Trigger the event
  $('#priceField').trigger('change');
});

function calcPrice() {
  $('#priceField').val(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="priceField" type="hidden">
<button id="applyBtn" type="button">Call .change()</button>
<button id="triggerBtn" type="button">Trigger</button>
<span id="price"></span>
```

But this is error prone, so I would **strongly** suggest to set the `$('#price').text()` value directly where you calculate the price instead. Can't really make any examples without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I would put the trigger call in `calcPrice()` so it doesn't have to be repeated.

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to simulate the calculation of the price by this method. And the trigger call is not repeated in the example, I wanted to make distinction between two ways to do the same thing I guess. Honestly unsure whether one or the other is better, don't like both. But if the OP needs to trigger, then these are possible solutions.